# find specfic tag and order by number

Tags: c#

I have a text that I want to go after finding a specific tag for example BA all the numbers in the order.

```
FORM_ADS  BA="1" BB="103" BC="000055512100" BD="0" BE="1" BF="13970806" S="11111" BT="1" BU="1" BV="6" BW="0" BX="0" BYY="16" BZ="15721120" CB="0" EB="13388" BAA="13313880" BAB="14793200" BAC="0" BAD="927920" BAE="0" BAF="-3416408"  


FORM_ADS  BA="2" BB="103" BC="000050476860" BD="0" BE="1" BF="13970806"  BS="11111" BT="1" BU="1" BV="6" BW="0" BX="0" BYY="16" BZ="14326424" CB="0" EB="13376" BAA="11238300" BAB="12487000" BAC="0" BAD="1839424" BAE="0" BAF="-3022728"  


FORM_ADS  BA="1" BB="103" BC="001740832930" BD="0" BE="1" BF="13970806" BS="11111" BT="1" BU="1" BV="6" BW="0" BX="0" BYY="16" BZ="18814350" CB="0" EB="13388" BAA="16025580" BAB="17806200" BAC="0" BAD="1008150" BAE="0" BAF="-3034878"    


FORM_ADS  BA="2" BB="103" BC="000050095071" BD="0" BE="1" BF="13970901" BR="0000106933" BS="11111" BT="1" BU="1" BV="6" BW="0" BX="0" BYY="16" BZ="3296900" CB="0" EB="8357" BAA="2967210" BAB="0" BAC="0" BAD="0" BAE="0" BAF="740378"
```

Comment: in this sample BA must start with 1 and end to 4

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask. Please show what you've tried so far and where you are having a problem.

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve] with sample inputs, and expected results based on those sample inputs.

Comment: [Regex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) is your friend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can capture any BA="#" with regex and then replace it with BA="{index}":

```
// read your text
string allText = Filre.ReadAllText(path);
string format = "BA=\"(.*?)\"";
int index = 1;
allText = Regex.Replace(allText, format, match =>  $"BA=\"{index++}\"");
// now write your text back to file
```

Comment: enter code here
{

            string allText = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(path1);
            allText += "\r\n";
            allText += System.IO.File.ReadAllText(path2);

            string format = "BA=\"(.*?)\"";
            MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(allText, format);
            List<string> numbers = matches.Cast<Match>().Select(x => x.Value).Select(x => x.Split('"')[1]).ToList();
            //now write to the created file
            System.IO.File.WriteAllText(newFilePath, allText);

}

Comment: @mohsentaherzadeh what's the problem?

Comment: hi roozbeh ,this code dont work   i have an string that save in alltext value,so i must find tag BA and sort all numbers by asc for exam first BA ia  BA="1" and second BA="2" and third is BA="1" that change to 3 and forth BA="2" that must be equal to 4 until n value....